# Python division operator acting strange when operands are negative

Tags: python, python-2.7, operator-keyword

I accidentally stumbled upon a strange behavior in python. 
Typing this peace of code in repl.

```
In [29]: 7 /-3
Out[29]: -3
```

Can find nowhere any reasonably explanation for this result. 
What is happening here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python integer division rounds results towards negative infinity.

For the reason why: http://python-history.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Comment: worth to mention, that in python 3 `/` operator will return float, and `//` will make a floor integer division. So in python 3: `7 /-3` is `-2.3333333333333335`, and `7 // -3` is `-3`

Comment: Though it's curious that the "-" is treated as a sign in first place.

Comment: @zoombya what do you mean, the unary minus?

Comment: It's terribly annoying that in python, `-1*(x/y) != (-1*x)/y` in all cases, which means that the language doesn't support the associative property of multiplication for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When doing integer division python rounds to the next lower integer(floor).
That is why if you compute `7/3` python will tell you it's `2`.
When you type `7/-3` it dose not become `-2` because that would not be the floor. `-3` is the next lower integer.

Answer (score 0):

While performing integer division the number is rounded to the lower int (`floor(x)` returns the maximum `n` in N such that `n <= x`). This means that for negative numbers the rounded number value will have  a higher absolute value (so `7/3 == floor(7//-3) == floor(-2.333)` returns `-3`).